# Best option to save Ionic 2 info in server with http?

Tags: ionic2

I have a question regarding the design/architecture in an Ionic2 application, although this could be related to any native app.

I'm developing an app where the user has to interact a lot (it's a game, actually) so I need to save status, options and many things. At the moment I have an API Rest so every time the user's information is updated I call the API to save the info via http. At the same time, to retrieve other users stats and info I need to get this info as well from the API, so I do this every time the user selects the appropriate screen.

I'm guessing this is not very efficient, so I want to use the Storage from Ionic to use the local storage and only save/read from the http API when the user enters the app or leaves.

The question is, is this a good strategy? I see flaws in both. How do I know the user has left the application? He could just have changed to another task in his phone and the app would actually be alive.

I'm guessing this is a very common situation in any app, so how is it resolved usually?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/ might help

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an API is called, the data is subscribed to a "variable", which is stored in MEMORY, not Storage. As soon as user exits app/cleans RAM that info is flushed. Don't worry about the data retrieval from HTTP-REST unless it is very huge.
As you asked, the strategy you are following(NOT using local storage) is correct.

And coming to efficiency,
Everything which is DISPLAYED on View is from Memory(RAM), when you fetch data from remote server the data is directly stored in memory, which can be accessed in 'Super Speed'.

But when you store in STORAGE(LocalStorage or whatever), it must be brought into RAM from Memory Card/InternalStorage of a mobile to access data.

According to me, Fetching HTTP REST Data is efficient when you fetch small packets of data whenever necessary, but DONT fetch all the data at a time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, the problem is not how efficient it is but that the application has to be able to work without a connection, and then synchronize whenever it's possible, so I have to use storage.